# Adding two dictionaries in a RDD in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, rdd

I have created and RDD where every element is a dictionary. (This is a sample. There are 30,000 keys

```
rdd.take(2)

[{'actor': 'brad',
  'good': 1,
  'bad': 0,
  'average': 0,}
 {'actor': 'tom',
  'good': 0,
  'bad': 1,
  'average': 1,}]
```

I am trying to perform arithmetic operations on the data, That is 
'actor': 'brad' and 'actor': 'tom', I want to add the other values having the same key

I did this:

```
d1=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['actor']=='brad').first()
d2=rdd.filter(lambda x: x['actor']=='tom').first()

dc={key: d1[key] + d2[key] for key in d1.keys() if key not in {'actor'} }
```

But since there are around 30,000 [keys] this is taking me lot of time. Can I optimize this by performing the addition using Spark's distributed operations. If so how?

Expected Output:

```
 [{'actor': 'brad',
      'good': 1,
      'bad': 1,
      'average': 1,}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a faster solution if you convert the RDD to Spark DF and groupby the key to sum up the values:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

a = [{'actor': 'brad', 'good': 1, 'bad': 0, 'average': 0,}, {'actor': 'tom','good': 0, 'bad': 1, 'average': 1,}, {'actor': 'brad', 'good': 1, 'bad': 0, 'average': 0,}, {'actor': 'tom','good': 0, 'bad': 1, 'average': 1,}]

jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(a) # In your case this step might not be necessary
main_df = sql.read.json(jsonRDD)
main_df = main_df.groupby('actor').sum()
```

Output :

```
main_df.show()

+-----+------------+--------+---------+
|actor|sum(average)|sum(bad)|sum(good)|
+-----+------------+--------+---------+
| brad|           0|       0|        2|
|  tom|           2|       2|        0|
+-----+------------+--------+---------+
```

EDIT 2:
    # You can rename the columns if you need with `withColumnRenamed()`

```
main_json = main_df.toJSON()
```

EDIT 1:

```
>>> main_df.rdd.map(lambda x: {x[0]: (x[1], x[2], x[3])}).collect()
[{u'brad': (0, 0, 2)}, {u'tom': (2, 2, 0)}]
```

Comment: I want to add the rdd1 and rdd2 values having the same key and create a new RDD

That is:

(1+0)+(0+1)+(0+1)= (1,1,1)

Comment: Please close the question by selecting an answer if your requirement is sufficed.

Comment: Expected Output:

 [{'actor': 'brad',
      'good': 1,
      'bad': 1,
      'average': 1,}]